CPU has doubled, Instruments shows SCNSceneRendererDelegate on 2 threads
Xcode has long showed CPU at about 25% for a SceneKit game I'm working on. But recently, that number suddenly jumped to about 45%.
Instruments seems to suggest that the scene's SCNSceneRendererDelegate method is running on 2 different threads simultaneously (unless I'm misunderstanding the data).
Here is a screenshot of Instruments. This is from whatever template Instruments uses when you click the Profile in Instruments button in the Xcode Debug Navigator. I've highlighted the relevant info in yellow:

Q: Is this run-on-2-threads paradigm by design -- or could this be related to the increase in CPU usage?

What changed on your end? Different Xcode? Different iOS device/simulator/iOS version? Source code changes? Perhaps a git bisect is in order to figure out what source code changes are associated with the CPU usage change?

@HalMueller Not sure about Xcode version, but I'm testing on the same physical devices -- so no change, there. iOS version might have changed, I'm not sure. And, unfortunately, I don't have the project under source control at the moment (I'm guessing that means git bisect won't help me). I realize I haven't done myself any favors, here. For the record, I now suspect that my theory about SCNSceneRendererDelegate running on two threads simultaneously simply means I'm misunderstanding Instruments.
